# Best practice to use jQuery to make a div click, and toggle slide up/down of sibling ul?

Tags: jquery

what is the best/cleanest practice using jQuery to make it so that when you click on the div with the ID "open", that it will then toggle slide open/close the sub menu sibling (not all sub menus)?

I ideally didn't want to use .next/.prev in case other html is added under the parent li and then it breaks it

```
<div class="mobilemenu">

    <li>
        <a href="/menu-item-1">Menu item 1</a>
        <div id="open">▼</div>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href=/menu-item-1/subitem1>Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href=/menu-item-1/subitem2>Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href=/menu-item-1/subitem3>Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>


    <li>
        <a href="/menu-item-2">Menu item 2</a>
        <div id="open">▼</div>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href=/menu-item-2/subitem1>Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href=/menu-item-2/subitem2>Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href=/menu-item-2/subitem3>Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/menu-item-1">Menu item 3</a>
        <div id="open">▼</div>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href=/menu-item-3/subitem1>Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href=/menu-item-3/subitem2>Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href=/menu-item-3/subitem3>Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: @Jack2505 requesting "best" anything is generally opinion based, which is off-topic.  See [ask] / [help/on-topic] / [help/dont-ask]

Comment: You can *link* the two items by giving them the same `data-` attribute then find them in your js eg `$("ul[data-link=" + $(this).data("link") + "]").slideDown()` alternatively go up using closest then down again, eg `$(this).closest("li").find("ul").slideDown()`

Answer (score 1):

The way i like to do this is to go up the DOM tree to the parent, then back down to find the target. I agree with you that using `next()` or `sibling()` can get kind of scary if any of the elements move. Here is an example using your code.

I changed your code a little bit just to make it easier to get this done.

** UPDATE

It's better to make the whole nav item clickable to open the dropdown because people may not know to click on the little arrow. In this case, Just include the parent link as one of the menu options like "View all..."

```js
/* Capture the click */
$(".mobilemenu > li > a.menu-item-parent").click(function(e) {
  /* Prevent href event */
  e.preventDefault();
  /* Get parent element */
  const par = $(this).closest("li");
  /* Get sub-menu element */
  const submenu = par.find("ul.submenu");
  /* Check if sub-menu is visible */
  if (submenu.is(":visible")) {
    /* If visible remove active class and slide up */
    par.removeClass("active");
    submenu.slideUp("fast");
  } else {
    /* If not visible add active class and slide down */
    par.removeClass("active").addClass("active");
    submenu.slideDown("fast");
  }
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mobilemenu,
.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobilemenu>li,
.mobilemenu .submenu>li {
  background: slategray;
}

.mobilemenu>li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid darkgray;
}

.mobilemenu>li>a,
.mobilemenu .submenu>li>a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px 42px 12px 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mobilemenu>li>a>.open {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: .7em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.mobilemenu>li>a>.open:before {
  content: "▼";
  display: block;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

.mobilemenu>li.active>a>.open:before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.mobilemenu .submenu {
  display: none;
}

.mobilemenu .submenu>li {
  background: coral;
}

.mobilemenu .submenu>li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mobilemenu">

  <li>
    <a href="/menu-item-1" class="menu-item-parent">
    Menu item 1
        <span class="open"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="/menu-item-1/subitem1">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu-item-1/subitem2">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu-item-1/subitem3">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="/menu-item-2" class="menu-item-parent">Menu item 2
        <span class="open"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="/menu-item-2/subitem1">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu-item-2/subitem2">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu-item-2/subitem3">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="/menu-item-1" class="menu-item-parent">Menu item 3
        <span class="open"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="/menu-item-3/subitem1">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu-item-3/subitem2">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu-item-3/subitem3">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much friend, got what I wanted to work perfect thanks to your code!

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer if it helped you.